# Error submiting application to orkut sandbox

Tags: xml, opensocial

I am trying to submit an Open Social application to Orkut Sandbox without success. My XML actually looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Module>
  <ModulePrefs title="App title" author_email="myemal@gmail.com" description="My test application" 
        author="My Name" screenshot="http://www.jogodireto.com/280x240/sonic-sky-chase.jpg" 
        thumbnail="http://i271.photobucket.com/albums/jj139/Igorstz/120x60-2.png">
        <Require feature="opensocial-data"/>
  </ModulePrefs>

  <Content view="canvas" 
    href="http://gadget-doc-examples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/opensocial-09/mycontent.html">
  </Content>
  <Content view="home">
    <![CDATA[
      Hello, home view!
    ]]>
  </Content>
</Module>
```

And when I try to submit it, I get the following error:

> Submit failed. Please ensure that the
>   gadget has title, description, author
>   email, thumbnail url, and screenshot
>   url defined, that you are an owner of
>   the gadget, and that the gadget is not
>   already submitted to any google
>   property.

Is there anything wrong with my xml? It is available in my website if I type in the browser its URL. Looks like I have met these requirements present in the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work, by using this URL to submit the application http://sandbox.orkut.com/Main#Developer and not the one I used before: The "Submit your application" link in http://sandbox.orkut.com/Main#AppDirectory